# Finding abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Find all abelian groups of order $2^83^45^6$.

I can find the total number of abelian groups but there are too many. I find the number of abelian groups 22.5.11. I can't find all the groups, so is there a short way to show all of them?

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheFundamentalTheoremOfFiniteAbelianGroups/

Comment: Just a guess, but a verbal description of how you obtained the count may be all that's expected. Have you asked your instructor...?

Comment: I have an exam next week and I'm working on what I think I'm missing on my own, so I didn't ask my teacher. While solving the question, I used the fundemental theorem of finding abelian groups. I write every abelian groups is a direct product of cyclic groups of prime-power order. But, I am not sure my work is clear and my solution is true. Cyclic groups a little bit difficult to understand for me. :)